Angle to Normalized Vector seems to only be returning in 45 degree increments
Im making a Raycaster style engine in Love2D, I'm using this function
function AngToVec(angle)
    local one = math.cos(math.rad(angle))
    local two = math.sin(math.rad(angle))
    local vec = { two, one }
    return vec
end

to take player angle and get a normalized vector to apply to movment, and this function to calculate and apply movment to player,
    player.Rot = AngToVec(player.Angle)
    local altRot = AngToVec(player.Angle + 90)

    -- Take input and apply to acceleration
    player.Accel[1] = (
        ((player.Input[1] * altRot[1]) * player.Speed) + ((-player.Input[2] * -player.Rot[1]) * player.Speed)
    )
    player.Accel[2] = (
        ((-player.Input[2] * player.Rot[2]) * player.Speed) + ((player.Input[1] * player.Rot[1]) * player.Speed)
    )

    -- Add Acceleration to Velocity
    for i, v in ipairs(Vec2) do
        player.Vel[i] = player.Vel[i] + player.Accel[i]
    end


[1] and [2] refer to X and Y respectively, input [1] is A/D L/R movment, input [2] is W/S U/D movment, the movment seems to only be snapping to the nearest 45 degree angle for movment, any help greatly appreciated.

What are player.Angle, player.Input and Vec2? What are their values?

Maybe vec = {math.cos(math.rad(angle)), math.sin(math.rad(angle))} as X and Y? Normally it's much easier to store angles in radians, not degrees.

''''player.angle'''' is angle player is looking stored in degrees, Vec2 is just used to iterate for loops twice
